# How to handle multi column search off 1 parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a Client table with the following fields within it that neeed to be searchable:

- FirstName
- LastName
- VerificationCode
- DateOfBirth

Currently I have a stored procedure that accepts a @criteria parameter and the where statement of the query is:

```
WHERE
    (FirstName like '%' + @Criteria + '%' or
    LastName like '%' + @Criteria + '%' or
    VerificationCode like '%' + @Criteria + '%')
```

I need the DateOfBirth to be searchable also through this @Criteria parameter and I wonder how it would be best to incorporate considering it is just one regular textbox on the frontend that passes through that value through the parameter?

Comment: Maybe this sounds stupid... but i'll suggest it anyway... :) since you're using LIKE, why not try Concatinating all columns that you will be using for lookup... :)

Comment: convert DOB to a string but will have to choose a format that is common to your users could be dd/mm/yyyy for example - what version of sql server is it? nb: *none of this is efficient for the dbms* performance may suck

Comment: Thanks guys, and yes @Used_By_Already, that was what I was thinking of doing too. Just wondering how others would approach the situation.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use [Azure Search](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2015/03/06/indexing-azure-sql-database-with-azure-search/) or use [Full-Text Search](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5086/full-text-indexing-with-azure-sql-database/). Those LIKE operators may generate scans.

Comment: Azure Search doesn't make "date" fields "searchable" it seems.
Likewise with FullTextSearch, can't search on date fields.

Comment: DatetimeOffset is supported based on the following document. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/supported-data-types

Comment: You can use > = < operators with date fields on full-text search.

Comment: You can't include a datefield as a part of a full-text search though.

Comment: Convert those dates to strings. Read this thread. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5a5f4c8c-1d5e-4d12-8e53-be8668943adc/full-text-search-using-conatains-predicate-on-datatime-and-numeric-type-columns-in-sql?forum=sqlsearch